# Updating an application inside Program Files

Tags: .net, windows

I have created a VB.net forms application and created an updater for it which downloads a zip file from a website and then extracts it to my applications installation directory. 
This works fine, except when the app has been installed inside the program files. I get access denied errors when I try to extract. Is there any way to get around this without disabling UAC or requiring users to change any settings on their end?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you should force the app to run as administrator.

Check this question: [How do I force my .NET application to run as administrator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-to-force-my-net-app-to-run-as-administrator-on-windows-7)